# How do I remove characters between forward slashes in a variable in php

Tags: php, string, variables, forward, slash

I have a string variable "/31/file.php" and would like to remove the "/31/" but the number 31 can be random so the deletion can't be fixed on the number 31 but on a certain number from 1-100.

Comment: You could either explode on the slash or use Regex (preg_replace()).

Comment: $exploded = explode ("/","/31/file.php");
is $exploded[1] = "file.php"?

Comment: http://3v4l.org/hEqIE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you can use [`basename`](http://php.net/basename):

```
echo basename("/31/file.php"); // "file.php"
```

PHP has some useful built in functions for manipulating file paths, like [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/pathinfo) and [`dirname`](http://php.net/dirname)